# allow acces to google forms when it is blocked on the network

Tags: proxy, google-forms

I'm trying to get people at a company to fill in a google forms survey with permissions from management.

The problem is that someone there has blocked all google features except search *(I know it's crazy)*.

The survey is fairly large and the question format is tailored to google forms so rewriting it in a different survey system is hardly an option.

I also cannot ask them all to install a proxy or vpn.

I tried conventional proxy sites but they are viewing only eg. they can't fill in the survey.

Are there any other methods I can try to allow the people to fill in my google form survey?

thanks!

Comment: You can embed a Google Form into an email and fill it out and submit it from the email.  But, when the Form is submitted, it opens another tab in the browser, and the URL to submit the Form will include "google.com"  So, I don't know if that would get blocked or not.  I'm assuming that it would.  Other than that, I don't know how you would do this.  You could embed a Google Form in a website, and have people visit the website.  I don't know if the embedded IFrame of the Google Form would get picked up by the company's system.

Comment: I think embedding in sth like an iframe wouldn't work because the page still comes from google and would be blocked